# Internal Link Active State

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I knew active state is not working on internal link.That's why i used below jquery code

```
$('.main-navigation .current-menu-item > a').click(function(){
     $('.main-navigation .current-menu-item > a').removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
  });
```

And its working fine.My question is if user directly visit url with internal link like

http://www.url.com#home

then obviously active class will not add in current menu item.How can i handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check for it on page load.

```
if(window.location.hash){
    var activeTab = window.location.hash;

    $('.main-navigation .current-menu-item > a').removeClass('active');
    $('.main-navigation a[href="'+activeTab+'"]').addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.Your code should work but for some reasons its not working in a[href="activeTab"].I also debug this console.debug(activeTab); and it return correct value but not in a[href="activeTab"].